# Error while testing promise with Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-rootscope

I've been writing some unit tests in Jasmine and I have a function that returns a promise in a service which I use in my own factory. I'm doing the following steps:

```
inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$q_, swIncludedService){
includeDeferred = q.defer();
includeDeferred.resolve();
spyOn(swIncludedServiceMock,'testMethod').andReturn(includeDeferred.promise);
});

it('....',function(){
rootScope.$apply();
expectSomething...
});
```

I did some debugging and it goes through my promise function but after finishing the last line it goes into StateBrowser and throws this error: Could find state for path.: $root.

Comment: You will need to add your method code co we know what happens after you resolve the promise. The code so far seems to be fine at first sight.

Comment: it doesn't look like you set `rootScope`-variable? or is just that you are not including that part of your test?

Comment: I set it, did not included in my code here.